# How to restrict the content type for signed upload url for Google Storage?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I would like to create a pre-signed upload url that enables the client to upload files directly to the bucket. The url should exceed after five minutes, prevent uploads of files that are greater than 1mb and only allow .jpg and .png files to be uploaded. I managed to put everything together except for the file type restriction. The documentation hasn't helped, unfortunately. How can you restrict the uploaded file to be something other than .jpg or .png?

```golang
policy, err := storage.GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4(keys.GetKeys().BUCKET_NAME, siteID+".png", &storage.PostPolicyV4Options{
    GoogleAccessID: conf.PrivateKeyID,
    PrivateKey:     conf.PrivateKey,
    Expires:        time.Now().Add(5 * time.Minute),
    Conditions: []storage.PostPolicyV4Condition{
        storage.ConditionContentLengthRange(0, 1<<20),
    },
})
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prevent images (or any specific content type)? If that is the case, it is not possible. Google checks the header but not the contents of the data stream. If your question is how to prevent uploads with the header Content-Type use `"eq", "$Content-Type", "text/plain"` To limit the upload size: `"content-length-range", 0, 1000000` https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document

Answer (score 1):

Just append `PostPolicyV4Options` by `Fields`

```
    Fields: &storage.PolicyV4Fields{
        // It MUST only be a text file.
        ContentType: "text/plain",
    },
```

Comment: Problem is, that you can only can specify one ContentType. In your case it would be something like "image/*"